# Listening to Eclipse editor focus

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to perform some actions every time an Eclipse editor gains focus. In other words I will like to listen to tab switch performed on each editor part. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `IPartLister` to listen to all part state changes and look for ones where the part is an editor:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

window.getPartService().addPartListener(listener);
```

The various methods of `IPartListener` are given an `IWorkbenchPart` parameter, you need to check if that is an instance of `IEditorPart`.